# Meaning of band width in ggplot geom_smooth lm

Tags: r, ggplot2

With the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=factor(cyl))) +
    geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

I can get this plot:

[image]

My question is how does the grey zone defined? What's the meaning of it.
And how can I play around with various parameter that control the width of that band?

Comment: It is the standard error.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

By default, it is the 95% confidence level interval for predictions from a linear model ("lm"). The documentation from `?geom_smooth` states that:

> The default stat for this geom is **stat_smooth** see that documentation for more options to control the underlying statistical transformation.

Digging one level deeper, doc from `?stat_smooth` tells us about the methods used to calculate the smoother's area.

For quick results, one can play with one of the arguments for **stat_smooth** which is `level` : *level of confidence interval to use (0.95 by default)*

By passing that parameter to **geom_smooth**, it is passed in turn to **stat_smooth**, so that if you wish to have a narrower region, you could use for instance .90 as a confidence level:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=factor(cyl))) +
    geom_smooth(method="lm", level=0.90)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What does confidence interval (CI) tells us here? How did you choose which is the 'ideal' level for CI?

Comment: There's no "ideal" level, only more or less conservative (prudent) ones. For what it tells us, I'd suggest looking into `?predict` and `?predict.lm`. Basically it indicates the "range" in which our predictions would be if we were to repeat the experiment (sampling) over and over. One sampling leads to a single straight line of predictions; taking into account variability of the data, the zones indicate a range of possible straight lines, if you will. By setting level at .9, we say "if we were to repeat the sampling over and over, 90% of the regression lines would be inside that grey zone".

Comment: Is ti possible to show something other than se? For example, the 10th and 90th quantiles of the data?

Comment: Why is it narrower the lower the chosen level is?

Comment: @Ben, it is narrower the lower the confidence interval, because the more the more one restricts the band the higher the chance that it was a fluke, and that the real regression curve falls outside.

Comment: @Ben It's always a trade-off between precision and certitude (or confidence). If you want to be 99% confident of capturing the populational value (parameter), then your estimation needs to accommodate for quite a bit of departure from the estimate obtained with your current sample. Using a low confidence level = getting more precision at the cost of a high risk of missing the target.

Comment: @SimonWoodward Maybe look into [quantile regression](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_quantile.html)

Comment: Is there a way to only show the lower confidence bound in 'se' ?

Answer (score 10):

It's the confidence interval. You can use `se=FALSE` if you do not want to display it. You can also use `level = 0.99` if you want to have a 99% CI instead of a 95% CI. See `?stat_smooth` for all the details.

Comment: Is there a way to only show the lower confidence bound in 'se' ? I