# How can I find the dimensions of the plotted area in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)

p<- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~x)
```

Can someone please show me how to compute the dimensions of the plotted area ( that is the area which has the grey background NOT including the legend) ?

Answer (score 0):

If I do not understand wrong the question, you are asking for the x and y limits of a graph. 
That can be set using: 
`scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10, 10))`
or 
`coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-10, 10))`. It is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots)

Otherwise, if you are asking about the area created through the lines, that is the 95% confidence interval of your lm model. To see a better explanation, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554796/meaning-of-band-width-in-ggplot-geom-smooth-lm)

Comment: I am asking the height and width in cms or inches of the plotted area.

Comment: Then it must be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867325/get-width-of-plot-area-in-ggplot2