# How to superimpose a 90% confidence band (pointwise) for linear regression in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am working with the forestfires dataset found here http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Forest+Fires. I have created a scatterplot for the relationship between temperature and area burned. Here is my graph. [Relationship b/w Temp and Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfeXO.png). I know that the 90% confidence interval is 0.2804346 to 1.864821 because I did confint, but I do not know how to superimpose this 90% confidence band on my graph. Any help would be appreciated!

```
mod1 = lm(area ~ temp, data = forestfires)
confint(mod1, 'temp', level=0.90)

ggplot(forestfires)+
  aes(x=temp, y=area)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
  scale_y_log10()+
  ggtitle("Relationship of Area Burned and Temperature")+
  xlab("Temperature")+
  ylab("Area")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Add to "level=0.90" to `geom_smooth()` ? Re https://stackoverflow.com/a/29555030/12957340

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. That was so simple thank you. I was looking for it on stack overflow but I kept seeing complicated solutions that I didn't need.

Comment: In my assignment, it says to add the (pointwise) 90% confidence band, this is the same thing right? I'm worried that pointwise means new lines or something.