# Increase width of ribbon when increasing size of linear model line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I am plotting a simple linear model with `ggplot2`. However, when I increase the size of the line, the ribbon does not change size (understandable). However, how would I scale the ribbon so that it matches the increase in line thickness?

Here is a simple example using the `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red")
```

[image]

As you can see when you increase size (I'm over exaggerating the size here), then more of the ribbon is covered up.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", size = 5)
```

[image]

Essentially, the ribbon only needs to extend out as much as the additional thickness of the line that is displacing/obscuring the ribbon.

**Expected Results**

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand; the shaded area represents the 95% confidence interval, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554796/meaning-of-band-width-in-ggplot-geom-smooth-lm.  Are you interested in showing that band 5x as wide?

Comment: @JonSpring Not 5x as large as that would make the ribbon a little too big. I added a little more of a description and image. Essentially, what I am trying to say is that if the line increases in thickness by say 1 cm, then the ribbon would need to expand by 0.5 cm on each side.

Comment: Why do you want this? The confidence band doesn't change if you change the line thickness. That means you don't want the ribbon to represent the confidence band. But that leads to the question what the ribbon is supposed to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", size = 5, 
              aes(ymin = after_stat(y - 5*se),
                  ymax = after_stat(y + 5*se)))
```

[image]

Comment: This seemed to be about the right thickness if I changed it to `2.5*se` (at least for size = 5).

Comment: Hmm, so you want the `se` ribbon (based on a numeric calculation related to the data) to be adjusted based on the print width of the line? That's a little tricky since different print settings (e.g. different resolution) will change the  line width. I hope an approximate manual solution suffices...