geom_smooth() producing a linear fit
I'm using R to model the tone contour (pitch) of words in a language and I have two main questions. Note that I am new to R and don't have a data science background, so any help is really appreciated.
My dataframe has the following structure:
 $ speaker  : Factor w/ 6 levels "KP","MK","MP",.. # speaker abbreviation
 $ file     : chr [1:117000] "aardvark" "aardvark" "aardvark" "aardvark" ... # english word
 $ position : num [1:117000] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... #repetition number (1, 2, 3)
 $ label    : chr [1:117000] "goo" "goo" "goo" "goo" ... # word in language
 $ tone     : chr [1:117000] "dHL-v" "dHL-v" "dHL-v" "dHL-v" ... # tone category
 $ sample   : num [1:117000] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... # sample point (time normalized)
 $ pitch    : num [1:117000] 98 98 98 98 98 ... # F0 in Hz
 $ normF0   : num [1:117000] -0.145 -0.145 -0.145 -0.145 -0.145 ... # zscore of pitch 

My goal is to output graphs which model pitch curves for each tonal category (df$tone). Each tone category has 100 time-normalized measurements done on 5 words repeated 3 times by 6 speakers (9,000 measurements per tone category). I would like to output a graph that averages all words said by all speakers for a given tone category, and a graph that averages all speakers by word for a given tone category.
Here's one graph I made with ggplot2 geom_smooth() for a given tone category:

Here's the graph for the same tone category averaged across speakers by word:

Question 1
For only one particular word in one tone category, geom_smooth() seems to be making a linear fit rather than a curved fit; look at tshaa (blue) below:

I know this is not an issue with my data, and when I plot using the loess method, R makes a curved (but not very smooth) fit.
This is the code I used to plot this graph, as well as the method and formula that R is using:
ggplot(subset(df, df$tone=="dHM-h"), mapping=aes(x=sample, y=pitch, color=label, fill=label))
+geom_smooth()
+xlab("Time (Normalized)")
+ylab("F0 (Hz)")
+ggtitle("dHM (Aspirated Depressors)")
+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
+coord_cartesian(ylim=c(120, 210))
+scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10))
+guides(fill = guide_legend(title="Word"), color= guide_legend(title="Word"))
> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula = 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'

Is there a way that I can adjust the plotting or smoothing function so that tshaa is fitted like the rest of the words?
Question 2
Perhaps related to the answer to the question above and the fact that I'm no data scientist, I am wondering: is there a better way to plot this data?
I don't entirely understand the implications of plotting it the way that I have, and in a lot of sources I've read with geom_smooth and ggplot2, people use factor() and grouping to separate their data into groups.
Instead, I'm just plotting subsets of my data by df$tone. When I do this, (for instance in the ML (Averaged) graph above, is R outputting a model that best fits the data averaged across all speakers? This is the code I used for the ML (Averaged) graph, and others like it; if you compare to the previous code, the only difference is that I'm just plotting all data for that tone category and not specifying fill or color:
ggplot(subset(df, df$tone=="ML"), mapping=aes(x=sample, y=pitch))
+geom_smooth()
+xlab("Time (Normalized)")
+ylab("F0 (Hz)")
+ggtitle("ML (Averaged)")
+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
+coord_cartesian(ylim=c(120, 210))
+scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10))

Thanks in advance!

Note that geom_smooth is showing the confidence interval, which relates to an estimate of the population average and is not the same as a standard deviation, which speaks to the variation between individual observations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554796/meaning-of-band-width-in-ggplot-geom-smooth-lm

Is geom_plot in the title a typo?

Thanks for catching that typo, I just fixed the title. And thanks also for explaining the shading on the plots! That helps so much, didn't realize that.

Try using facet_wrap(~label) instead of assigning label to color and fill. The facet_wrap will give you a sub plot for each label and it will be easier to see what is going on. Also, try adding geom_point() to the plot to see how well the smoothed lines match the data scatter.

Since you have a lot of data, I assume ggplot2 is using mgcv::gam to create the smooths. mgcv::gam does penalized regression and optimizes the "smoothness". It is usually pretty good at separating signal and noise with default settings. You haven't demonstrated that it failed here but you might want to fit the model outside ggplot2 and use mgcv::gam.check. You could also switch off the optimization of smoothness and fix the k parameter to some arbitrary value.

I figured out a simple fix - in the geom_smooth() function, I specified formula=y~s(x, bs="cr") and that fixed the issue. By default, R was using the GAM formula, but it was specifying bs="cs" which seems to have been oversimplifying the smooth for that one word.
